# CombinePDF.parse is unable to process some PDF files

Tags: combine-pdf

**Tech Stack used**

Ruby 2.5.8, Rails 5.0.7, Ruby Gems: combine_pdf

Here is my sample code that is working for most of the PDF Urls hosted in S3, except one PDF.

```rb
@pdf = CombinePDF.new
@pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(s3_pdf_url)).body)
@pdf = @pdf.to_pdf
```

Above code is working as expected for 90% of the PDF files, there is one file that is not working for me. I don't see any exceptions generated and not sure how to debug it.

CombinePDF do generates the final pdf and it is blank as shown in this [screenshot_link.](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4639903/191512238-0a2ab7cc-3512-440b-83e6-b7173770ab68.png)

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Here is my another example code. I'm writing original S3 PDF into the Tempfile and using `CombinePDF.load()` to combine the PDF which is there inside tempfile. But still this PDF is not combined and no exception generated. When I opened tempfile(MyPDF20220921-21580-1qzgy1u.pdf) I can see and access PDF.

```
path = s3_pdf_url
t = Tempfile.new(["MyPDF", '.pdf'])
t.write(open(path).read.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8))
t.close
@pdf = CombinePDF.load t.path
@pdf = @pdf.to_pdf
```

Comment: Yes. File seems corrupted although it is accessible on browser but not valid to merge.

Comment: I already tried by passing argument `allow_optional_content: true`. But that so called corrupted file is not seen in the final combined PDF output. However other 2 PDF files are seen in the final output.

Comment: `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` this err is throwing while file write, I guess Ruby tries to apply default character encoding while`file.write` so i used it to write file without error. Also I have tried by `File.open(t.path, 'wb')` opening the temp file in `wb` mode and then I write the file. But still pdf is not merged, so, this later approach (open the file in binary mode and write it with original file) also corrupted the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248263/discussion-between-siv-rj-and-k-j).